# ListView with fixed header and footer programmatically

Tags: android, listview, header

So I'm trying to make a listView with a fixed header and footer programmatically, but I've already looked and I can't just fix the header using the addHeader on the listView, so I'm trying to use a linearlayout with others linearlayout which would be my fixed header and footer and between both the header and the footer a listview, but when I try the listView just covers the entiry screen, I've used relativelayout to try to force the header to be above the listView but I can't. I've literally started using android studio and making android programs yesterday so I'm trying to learn the more that I can. But I've looked on the internet and nothing that I've found has helped me, because the examples used a lot of xml, and I'm trying to use as the last resource. For compatibility reasons I'm using the 16 version of the android.

The xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_user_event_search"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="takeme.testers.UserEventSearch">

</RelativeLayout>
```

The java file:

```
private static String[] items = { "test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4",
        "test 5", "test 6", "test 7", "test 8", "test 9", "test 10",
        "test 11", "test 12", "test 13", "test 14", "test 15"};

private ListView eventsView;
private LinearLayout mainLayout, viewHeader, viewFooter, listViewHeader;
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1, params2, params3;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    this.setContentView(mainLayout);
    params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    viewHeader = new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    viewHeader.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    viewHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    viewHeader.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 100));
    viewHeader.setId(R.id.l0);
    viewHeader.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);



    eventsView = new ListView(this.getApplicationContext());
    eventsView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    eventsView.setId(R.id.l1);
    eventsView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300));
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, viewHeader.getId());


    listViewHeader = new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    listViewHeader.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    listViewHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    listViewHeader.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));

    eventsView.addHeaderView(listViewHeader, null, false);


    viewFooter = new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    viewFooter.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    viewFooter.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    viewFooter.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    viewFooter.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 100));
    viewFooter.setId(R.id.l2);
    params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, eventsView.getId());

    this.addContentView(viewHeader, params1);
    this.addContentView(eventsView, params2);
    this.addContentView(viewFooter, params3);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    eventsView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The result at the moment:

[image]

[image]

Comment: By fixed header and footer, you mean they're always on screen?  If so, don't make them headers and footers.  Just make them normal views, and put the ListView in between them (easiest way is a RelativeLayout parent and put the list layout_above the footer and layout_below the header.

Comment: Yes, by fixed header and footer I mean always on screen. And that's what I'm trying to do. But as I've said I'm trying to do it programmatically and not just using the designer.

Comment: 1)Why?  That's way harder.  Nobody dynamically creates views unless they absolutely have to.  You'd fail a code review or interview if you did that. 2)Even ignoring that-  you could still do what I told you programmatically.  That's the standard way of doing it.  All 3 views in a relative layout with rules on the list to put it in between the two (and nail the header and footer to parent top and bottom respectively).

Comment: @GabeSechan 1) Because I'm trying to learn and that's my way of learning best, as I said I've only began learning how to make android programs and I've started yesterday. 2) how can i do it programmatically? Because the code that is shown above is how I've tried to do something similar to what you've said. Can you post some example or say what's wrong about what I've written? Thank you anyway, don't worry on an interview or at a proper code I'll do on xml what is supposed to be there.